# async.timesLimit() will not accept a valid callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, mocha.js, async.js

**PROBLEM**

I am working with an API using the async library for node. I've hit an obstacle that I just can't seem to get around.

I am modifying an object in a database through a RESTful API. The command I'm using is called `ModifyObject` and it works. I am making another function that allows me to edit multiple objects at once asynchronously. But, I don't want to hit my server with 100 requests at once, so I'm using `async.timesLimit()`. You can find [the documentation for this function here](https://github.com/caolan/async#times). Here is my `shared.js` utility function file:

```js
var async = require('async');

exports.ModifyObject = function (objectId, data, callback) {
    setup.api()
        .json()
        .patch('/Object(' + objectId + ')')
        .header("X-ApiKey", setup.apiKey())
        .send(data)
        .end(function (err, res, body) {
          if(err) throw err;
          callback(res);
    });
};

exports.ModifyMultipleObjects = function (arrayOfObjectIds, data, callback) {
    var failedArray = [];
    async.timesLimit(arrayOfObjectIds.length, 3, function (n, next) {
        exports.ModifyObject(arrayOfObjectIds[n], data, function (response) {
            if(response.statusCode != 204) failedArray.push("Failed to modify object: " + arrayOfObjectIds[n]);
            next(null);
        });
    }, function (err, failedArray) {
        if(err) throw err;
        callback(failedArray);
    });
};
```

`data` is a JSON object.

So, I create multiple objects, then I call `ModifyMultipleObjects` on an array of their ids, but I get `TypeError: undefined is not a function` thrown at me. Here is how I'm calling this in a mocha test:

```js
var shared = require('../shared.js');

describe('test', function () {
    it('modify multiple objects', function (done) {
        var modData = {
            "propA": 100,
            "propB": 200
        };
        shared.ModifyMultipleObjects(objArray, modData, function (errArr) {
            if(errArr.length > 0) throw new Error(errArr);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

The `objArray` is valid. I have checked this multiple times.

**Error Stacktrace**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property undefined is not a function
at Object.exports.ModifyMultipleObjects(C:blahblahblah\shared.js:1374:8)
at Context.<anonymous> (C:\blahblahblah\general\modify_multiple_ojbects.js:46:10)
```

The line from `modify_multiple_objects.js` is:

`shared.ModifyMultipleObjects(objArray, modData, function (errArr) {`

The line from `shared.js` is:

`async.timesLimit(arrayOfObjectIds.length, 3, function (n, next) {`

Comment: How are you requiring the `shared.ModifyMultipleObjects`? Can we see the code for this?

Comment: sorry, lastly, could you show us your stack trace leading up to `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: How are you importing `async.js`? Btw, why don't you just use `async.eachLimit`?

Comment: I'm requiring async the standard way only in `shared.js`. I tried eachLimit but it only runs the iterator the limit number of times and then moves on. So if I have 10 objects I want to modify and set the limit as 5, it modifies 5 and then leaves the rest there umodified. I'm using fiddler to intercept the network traffic.

Comment: I deleted my answer because didn't solve your problem. I couldn't reproduce your error. My code is the same than yours and everything works fine. Maybe the error is in the parts I couldn't reproduce.

Comment: That's weird. I hope this isn't some deeper problem with my node/async install, processor, os, or some weird config setting somewhere.

Comment: Could you try to reproduce your error on another machine? Maybe a vagrant machine or any virtual.

Comment: I'll try to set that up. For now I'm using a different implementation of `async.eachLimit()` as suggested by @Bergi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote both functions using `async.timesLimit()` and `async.eachLimit()` (as suggested by @Bergi).

`eachLimit()`:

```js
    async.eachLimit(objectIds, 5, function (item, next) {
        exports.ModifyObject(item, data, function (res) {
            if (res.statusCode != 204) throw new Error("failed to modify object " + item);
            next();
        }, function (err) {
            callback();
        });
    });
```

`timesLimit()`:

```js
    async.timesLimit(objectIds.length, 5, function (n, next) {
        exports.ModifyObject(objectIds[n], data, function (res) {
            if(res.statusCode != 204) throw new Error("failed to modify object " + objectIds[n]);
            next();
        });
    }, function (err) {
        callback();
    });
```

The `timesLimit()` function throws the same `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error as stated in the question.

However, `eachLimit()` works perfectly. I don't understand why though. As far as I can tell, `timesLimit()` is written correctly, and these two functions should be identical.